# Unable to locate the web element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

Here is my test case:

1. Launch the web browser and open the application under test –
   http://google.com
2. Enter the keyword in the `Google Search` text box by which we would
   want to make the request.

Below is my Script:

```
WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String title = "http://www.google.com";
Driver.get(title);  
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sb_ifc0']")).sendKeys("selenium");
```

Answer (score 3):

This works fine.

```
String title="http://www.google.com"; 

Driver.get(title); 

Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys("Selenium");
```

//clicks on the search button

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have used incorrect xpath , Please update code as per below :

```
WebDriver Driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 

String title="http://www.google.com"; 

Driver.get(title); 

Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys("Selenium");
```

Hope this will work , For me it is working.

Answer (score 1):

If it already has an id identifier, there is no need for XPath.

```
Driver.findElement(By.ID("lst-ib")).sendKeys("selenium");
```